# Is there a summary of Varoufakis' EuroLeaks?

Tags: european-union, reference-request, greece, summary-request

As some kind of protest against the EU's latest action(s), former finance minister of Greece Varoufakis has [released](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDah_g3IzyM&vl=en) some tapes of his conversations with the Troika etc., which seem to date back to 2015.

It seems the mainstream press hasn't covered this much if at all. So, is there any sort of summary of what (in anything) interesting can be learned from those tapes e.g. in terms of EU negotiation tactics? Or is it "nothing new" in all of that?

Comment: https://euroleaks.diem25.org/leaks/ -  You might find something of interest in the "explainers" section.